# ffmpeg hls_time option is not working with h264_nvenc

Tags: ffmpeg

I want splitting video into HLS slice using `-hls_time`, but only `-codec copy` can use this.

I have tried adding key frame like this but still can't use

`-force_key_frames expr:"gte(t,n_forced*1)"`

This is code that can use `-hls_time`

`ffmpeg -i "/content/test.mp4" -codec copy -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 6 /content/'480p.m3u8'`


And this is code that `-hls_time` not work

`ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -i "/content/test.mp4" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -gpu 0 -b:v 1400000 -force_key_frames expr:"gte(t,n_forced*1)" -hls_time 6 -s 848x480 "/content/480p.m3u8"`

Comment: Please update your ffmpeg to the latest version (preferably latest on github). To see if problem still exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just fixed it by adding
`-hls_flags split_by_time` to the code

So it look like this:

`ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -i "/content/test.mp4" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -gpu 0 -b:v 1400000 -hls_flags split_by_time -hls_time 6 -s 848x480 "/content/480p.m3u8"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ffmpeg build version 3.4.8, and it works fine with GPU without any `hls_flags`